# White-out highlight on VS Help Pop-up?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image]

I've downloaded several VS themes from https://studiostyl.es/ and all of them are giving me a white highlight on these helper pop-ups. How do I get rid of that? I'm currently using Son of Obsidian, but this has also happened on Selenitic and Ragnarok. And please tell me what those pop-ups are called so I don't sound like such a novice in the future.

Note: In the past I screwed around with customizing the default Dark theme because I did not like the color of highlighting when doing a Find All References. Problem is I do not recall exactly what I changed; however I would not expect that to affect these.

EDIT: 
[image]

I may have found it, but I cannot edit the background.

EDIT 2: I found settings to change and a result I'm okay with.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm at Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Show Settings For: Text Editor. I am not seeing Signature Help under Display items.

Comment: Hmm, never mind. That's probably from an extension I have installed. One of your colors is definitely wrong, though. The dark colored schemes are changing the background color of the tooltip without changing the background color of that text to match. I'd just hunt around until I found the right option. Maybe someone knows what it is. I don't have VS 2012 installed to check.